# submit spark job to dataproc

Tags: java, apache-spark, google-cloud-dataproc

When I submit my shaded JAR to a local standalone cluster, it works fine. However, when I submit it to a Dataproc cluster, I encounter the error "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError", even though the class exists in the Maven dependency.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Try copying the JAR to a GCS bucket and including that in the [--jar parameter](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataproc/jobs/submit/spark#--jars) when you submit the job.